# Material Design Lite - Card supporting text not expanding with bigger cards when within a grid

Tags: html, css, material-design

I'm trying to build a website using MDL. However, when using cards within a grid, the card actions don't align to the bottom when card are smaller than others in the row, like this:

[image: Misaligned card actions]

It appears to be that the supporting text does not expand like I wanted it to, but not sure how I go about making that so. Here is the relevant snippet from the HTML:

```
<!-- Content -->
<main class="mdl-layout__content">
    <div class="mdl-grid">

        <!-- Short supporting text -->
        <div class="home-card mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col mdl-cell--8-col-tablet mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp">
            <div class="mdl-card__title">
                <h2 class="mdl-card__title-text">Blog</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text">
                A fairly recent addition detailing some of the work done on current projects.
            </div>
            <div class="mdl-card__actions mdl-card--border">
                <a class="mdl-button mdl-button--colored mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect">Visit Blog</a>
            </div>
            <div class="mdl-card__menu">
                <button class="mdl-button mdl-button--icon mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect">
                    <i class="material-icons">share</i>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Long supporting text -->
        <div class="home-card mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col mdl-cell--8-col-tablet mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp">
            <div class="mdl-card__title">
                <h2 class="mdl-card__title-text">Blog</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text">
                A fairly recent addition detailing some of the work done on current projects.
                A fairly recent addition detailing some of the work done on current projects.
            </div>
            <div class="mdl-card__actions mdl-card--border">
                <a class="mdl-button mdl-button--colored mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect">Visit Blog</a>
            </div>
            <div class="mdl-card__menu">
                <button class="mdl-button mdl-button--icon mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect">
                    <i class="material-icons">share</i>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
```

...and the CSS:

```
.home-card > .mdl-card__title {
    color: #fff;
    height: 176px;
    background: url('../assets/coding-banner.jpg') center / cover;
    padding: 0
}
.home-card > .mdl-card__title > .mdl-card__title-text {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 16px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
.home-card > .mdl-card__menu {
    color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Derp. Adding `mdl-card--expand` to the supporting text div is what I needed.

```
<div class="mdl-card__supporting-text mdl-card--expand">
    A fairly recent addition detailing some of the work done on current projects.
</div>
```